# DataError: value too long for type character varying(10)

Tags: django, postgresql

The project which I developed contains two forms in two different pages with one text field which is common to both of them. One page text field is working fine but other page text field is giving this error when submitting the form. I couldn't get a solution from other questions of this type. All the parameters for the text field in both models is the same but this error is showing up.

```
class ReviewDetails(models.Model):

    eid=models.ForeignKey('mtsauth.EditorReviewer',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ArticleId=models.ForeignKey('mtsauth.AuthorMS',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hypothesis=models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False)
    writing = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False)
    originality = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False)
    methodology = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False)
    relevance = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False)
    refcited = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False)
    assesment=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    comment_Author=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    comment_EditorOffice=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

    status=models.CharField(max_length=10,default="None",blank=False,null=False)
    rating=models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return repr(self.ArticleId).encode('utf-8')


#Model to store second cycle of peer process comments

class FinalReviewDetails(models.Model):

    eridSec=models.ForeignKey('mtsauth.EditorReviewer',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ArticleId=models.ForeignKey('mtsauth.AuthorMS',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment_Author1=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

    assesment=models.CharField(max_length=10,default="None",blank=True,null=True)
    followups = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, default="None")

    status=models.CharField(max_length=10,default="Pending",blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return repr(self.ArticleId)
```

Stack trace Error:

```
Internal Server Error: /ReviewProcess/revisedcomments.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Devadanam/Desktop/django_project_postgresql/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/Devadanam/Desktop/django_project_postgresql/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/Users/Devadanam/Desktop/django_project_postgresql/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
```

Comment: please share yor models

Comment: please share your code, and post the stack trace and then ask your question..

Comment: added the code and stack error, could you please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that `max_length=10` means the maximum acceptable length for your string, for field `assesment` in model `ReviewDetails` max_length is 100 but in `FinalReviewDetails` it's 10

increase the `max_length` for your fields, create a migration file (`makemigrations`), `migrate` your db and everything will work fine

Comment: thanks @aliva , i overlooked the assesment, I thought the error is about comment_Author field.